# How I can fixed the text in elementor pro wordpress to left

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How I can change this : (photo)

[image]

To this: (photo)

(!) Dosen't work with: text-align, text-justify, etc.

[image]

Comment: can you share your current code for this?  It will help to direct you in the right direction.

Comment: Isn't code for this in Wordpress Elementor it is one Layout ("Edit Price List");

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way to achieve that by creating a custom html table

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.second{
  width: 35%;
  border-left:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td class="second">44$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td class="second">$55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >Item 3</td>
        <td class="second">$66</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td class="second">$88</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 5</td>
        <td class="second">$99</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
    <!-- DivTable.com -->
```

Comment: Isn't code for this in Wordpress Elementor it is one Layout ("Edit Price List");